# CFileDialog with realtive path

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I currently maintenance an old MFC application and have problems with opening file dialogs. The Program has multiple different parts were the user select files for loading, eg sound, video and other program specific formats.

Opening a dialog should always open in a "specific" folder, depending on the file ending. Giving an directory path that contains "..\" will accept and the Dialog opens with the "last selected file".

```
CString fileDirectory = myHelper.getPath();
// fileDirectory  is now "C:\coding\svn\source\MyProgram\..\..\bin\..\data\..\Audio\"
CFileDialog FileDialog(true, _T("MP3;WAV"), _T(fileDirectory), OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, _T("All music files (*.WAV;*.MP3)));

if (FileDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
{ ... }
```

I use different CDialog classes (about 15, eg for editing audiofiles, for videofiles) and they all have similar code for opening dialogs like above.

How can i support the relative paths for the CFileDialog?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion, that `CFileDialog` does not support relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

The `CFileDialog` supports setting up initial/default folder. Here is the code snippet that demonstrates how to use it:

```
    const TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("Parameter Files (*.npf)|*.npf|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, _T("npf"), NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilter, this); 
    CString sParametersDir(CUtility::GetParametersDir());
    dlg.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = sParametersDir.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH);    
    if(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        m_ParametersFileEdit.SetWindowText(dlg.GetPathName());
    }

    sParametersDir.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Also regarding your code. There is no need to use `_T()` macro for `CString` objects. The `CString` class does support UNICODE automatically. The `_T()` macro should only be used for string literals.

You can use `CPath` class to normalize file path.

```
CPath path(sPath);
path.AddBackslash();
path.Append(_T("Config"));
path.Canonicalize();
```

Comment: *"There is no need to use `_T()` macro for `CString` objects."* - In fact, if it compiles at all then you haven't defined the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol. While common with really old code, consider switching to Unicode.

Comment: Per the [`CFileDialog` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx#cfiledialog__m_ofn): "*Windows Vista style file dialogs do not support certain members and flags of the CFileDialog. As a result, these will have no effect.*" `m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir` is on the list of fields that are ignored.

Comment: The [`OPENFILENAME` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) describes the actual behavior of `lpstrInitialDir` on various OS versions. Most importantly, `lpstrInitialDir` *CAN* be ignored and the user's last selected directory used instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The documentation for `CFileDialog` must be wrong. `CFileDialog` will accept `lpstrInitialDir` and sends it to `IFileDialog::SetFolder`. However `lpstrInitialDir` is ignored if a filename with full path is also provided, in which case the folder of that file will be used instead (in this case there is no default filename)